# DB2 Function not working, can't find the typo Reason: SQL Error [42601]

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400, dbeaver

I keep getting the error:

Error occurred during SQL script execution

Reason:
SQL Error [42601]: [SQL0104] Token  is ongeldig. Geldige tokens: ;.

What is my typo, I'm doing wrong here?
I have tried to find the problem by testing parts.
It have something to do with the way I use the IF and END IF statements.

Regards,

Marcel

```
CREATE FUNCTION BHPPGMP001.EXTRACTORDERNRFROMSTRING(rff1154a__Cr CHAR(35), rff1154b__Op CHAR(35))
RETURNS CHAR(11)
BEGIN 

    DECLARE ordernumber CHAR(35);
    DECLARE ordernrStripped CHAR(35);
    DECLARE ordernumberLength INTEGER;
    DECLARE pos INTEGER;
    DECLARE delimenters CHAR(4);

    SET ordernumber = '';
    
    IF rff1154a__Cr <> '' THEN 
        SET ordernumber = rff1154a__Cr;
        
        IF INSTR('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', SUBSTRING(rff1154a__Cr, 1)) > 0 AND rff1154b__Op <> '' THEN
            SET ordernumber = rff1154b__Op;
        END IF;
    ELSE
        IF rff1154b__Op <> '' THEN
            SET ordernumber = rff1154b__Op;
        END IF;
    END IF;
/*
    IF ordernumber <> '' THEN   
        
        SET ordernrStripped = ordernumbr;
        SET ordernrStripped = REPLACE(ordernumber, '/', '');
        SET ordernrStripped = REPLACE(ordernrStripped, '\', '');
        SET ordernrStripped = REPLACE(ordernrStripped, ' ', '');
        SET ordernrStripped = REPLACE(ordernrStripped, '-', '');
        SET ordernummerLengte = LENGTH(ordernrStripped);
        
        IF ordernumberLength > 10 THEN  
            
            IF INTEGER(SUBSTRING(ordernrStripped, 1, 11)) IS NOT NULL THEN
                SET ordernumber = SUBSTRING(ordernrStripped, 1, 11);
            END IF;
        ELSE
            IF ordernumberLength >= 18 THEN
            
                SET delimeters = '/\ -';
                SET pos = INSTR(delimeters, SUBSTRING(ordernumber,7,1));
                
                IF (pos > 0) THEN
                    SET ordernrStripped = SUBSTRING(ordernumber, LOCATE(SUBSTRING(delimeters, pos, 1),ordernumber)+1);
                    SET ordernrStripped = REPLACE(ordernrStripped, '/', '');
                    SET ordernrStripped = REPLACE(ordernrStripped, '\', '');
                    SET ordernrStripped = REPLACE(ordernrStripped, ' ', '');
                    SET ordernrStripped = REPLACE(ordernrStripped, '-', '');
                
                    IF INTEGER(SUBSTRING(ordernrStripped, 1, 11)) IS NOT NULL THEN
                        SET ordernumber = SUBSTRING(ordernrStripped, 1, 11);
                    END IF;
                END IF;
            END IF;
        END IF;
        
    END IF;
    */
    RETURN ordernumber;
END;
```

Update, removed the commented END IF so each IF has an END IF.

Update: We use version 7.3 of de iSeries (AS400).

Comment: Each and every `IF` statement must have a matching `END IF` but in your question you have commented-out (`--`) two such `end if` . Also, you must configure your tool (dbeaver?) to specify an alternative statement-delimiter (for example many people use the @ character) and use that character at the end of the block (end of the function).

Comment: Hello mao,

Thanks for your suggestion. It doesn't work. If I use @ as delimiter I get the following error: 

Error occurred during SQL script execution

Reason:
SQL Error [42601]: [SQL0104] Token @ is ongeldig. Geldige tokens: NOT DEFAULT CONSTANT.

Comment: Doesn't point me to the problem. I have worked with MySQL/MS-SQL, db2 on i Series (AS400) is not my expertise.

Comment: Added db2-400 tag for i-series.  You need to know the version of the i-series and write this into the question. The platform+version always matters with Db2-server, syntax varies between platforms and between versions, so something that compiles for one platform can fail to compile on a different platform or different version. Remember that the final END in the function should appear END@  (not END;@) if you chose @ as the alternative statement delimiter.

Comment: @smartduck What tool do you use to run this statement?

Comment: Hello @Mark,
I use dBeaver. I will check if I can run the statement in Eclipse.

Comment: Tested the script in System i Navigator and it works! So dBeaver is the problem.

Comment: Have you really set the statement delimiter in the dbeaver properties to `@`, or are you just trying to use it in your statement without such a setting?

Comment: For now I use Navigator to add my functions. I will take a look at the dBeaver settings later. I will post the solution later.